# Save method is not working for products

Tags: magento, methods, save, magento-1.9, product

I want to resave all products programmatically. So I am trying to use the below code to achieve it. But the save method is not working in it.

I have placed the code in the root directory of my Magento 1.9 installation. Can anyone kindly let me know how can I make it work?

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

// require magento core
require_once 'app/Mage.php';

// execute on admin store
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();


foreach($products as $product) {
    echo $product->getData('sku') . '<br/>';
    // save the product
    $product->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to save product, so if any error or exception occurred then it will display that and that will help full for you to fix the issue.Also update any attribute so you can see if that is updated or not.

```
try
{
    $product->save();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    //print the exception
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```